# How to traversing a webtable in karate framework and storing the each row

Tags: karate

Webtable in UI, need to read each row for certain columns match and pick any one row for further processing

What logic would be applied

expected is the script should able to extract each row (5 columns) and store as a list or map
and then after the few columns match, the entire row should be clicked for further processing in UI